# Room Thermostat, Cylinder Thermostat and Central Heating pump wiring

Tags: wiring, central-heating

I have a water cylinder that is heated from a wood burner with a back boiler.

The cylinder is also connected to the central heating system (via coil inside the cylinder) and a separate pump.

When the cylinder is at a set temperature and the room thermostat is below a set temperature I would like to start the pump for the central heating.

The room thermostat I have has live, neutral and call. (Drayton RTS1)
The cylinder thermostat has COM, N.C., N.O., Earth ([Danfoss ATC Cylinder Thermostat](http://www.free-instruction-manuals.com/pdf/pa_458050.pdf))
The pump has Live and Neutral (Grundfos 15-60/130 [similar to this](https://uk.grundfos.com/products/find-product/ups2.html))

I'm in the UK so this is all 230/240V

How should I wire this up for my required behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide a make and model for the cylinder thermostat? Also, how many HP is the pump?

Comment: I've added the model of the thermostat and pump and links to their specs. I couldn't find the exact pump model but it is an older version of the linked model

Comment: I take it you're running brand new twin-and-earth for this, or are there cables already in the walls?

Comment: Yes new wiring, there are existing cables but I'm not sure where they are all going so much easier to do it from scratch.

Comment: Are you pulling a new homerun from the consumer unit, or is mains already available at one of these three locations?

Comment: mains is already available.

Comment: Which location is mains already available at?